# How to import multiple images with WebPack 5

Tags: javascript, image, webpack, ecmascript-6, import

Using webpack 5, I have a folder that contains 40 images within my project. I want to dynamically import a specific image depending on what a user searches for in the DOM. Currently the only way I can figure out how to load my images is to go one by one and write:

```
import Coffee from '../assets/coffee.svg"
```

The problem with this is, is that I don't want to have to write 40 import statements. I've looked online for an answer but it seems like most of the answers are related specifically to React JS.

Comment: You should load them dinamically, having 40 images when the user may only use one based on its search its not a good idea. Import is usefull for static assets, but the case you are presenting is input-based.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out my problem by using require.

```
 const coffee = require(`../assets/icons/${drink.name}.svg`);
```